# mysql query error when using if condition

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT tu.begin_date, tm.MAGAZINE_ID,`MAGAZINE_NAME`, CASE WHEN ts.no_of_issues IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ts.no_of_issues END AS Subscription_Type, 
 CASE WHEN 
   IF(tu.customer_currency = 'USD', 54 * tu.customer_currency) 
   ELSE IF(tu.customer_currency = 'CAD', 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency) 
   END AS sale_price_inr,
 tu.developer_proceeds as orginal_rate, tu.customer_currency as orginal_currency
 FROM `tbl_itunes_report` tu
 LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine_subscription ts ON ts.subscription_key = tu.sku_key
 LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine_issue ti ON ti.PurchaseKey = tu.sku_key AND ti.OS_SELECT = 0
 LEFT JOIN tbl_magazine tm ON tm.magazine_id = ts.magazine_id
 OR tm.magazine_id = ti.magazine_id
 WHERE `product_type_identifier` LIKE 'IA%'
 AND
 (
     ts.subscription_key IS NOT NULL
     OR ti.PurchaseKey IS NOT NULL
 )
 AND tu.begin_date >= '2012-04-01' AND tu.begin_date <= '2013-04-01'
```

This is my query. But i excecute this query i got an error that

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ELSE IF(tu.customer_currency = 'CAD', 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency) END A' at line 3
```

if any one know this please help me. i am new to this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 ...
 CASE WHEN 
 IF(tu.customer_currency = 'USD', 54 * tu.customer_currency) 
 ELSE IF(tu.customer_currency = 'CAD', 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency) 
 END AS sale_price_inr
 ...
```

to

```
...
CASE WHEN tu.customer_currency = 'USD' THEN 54 * tu.customer_currency
     WHEN tu.customer_currency = 'CAD' THEN 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency 
 END AS sale_price_inr
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is different syntax for IF statement and IF function, you are using IF function with syntax of IF Statement, please change below line

```
IF(tu.customer_currency = 'USD', 54 * tu.customer_currency) 
 ELSE IF(tu.customer_currency = 'CAD', 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency)
```

to

```
CASE WHEN tu.customer_currency = 'USD' THEN 54 * tu.customer_currency
     WHEN tu.customer_currency = 'CAD' THEN 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency 
 END AS sale_price_inr
```

OR

```
IF(tu.customer_currency = 'USD', 54 * tu.customer_currency, 1.0250 * tu.customer_currency)
```